# Button pressed Image background set from Dreawable folder Using Array

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1;
        final ImageView image;

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
                       Drawable dreaw =                          getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("d002_p00"+j, "dreaw",getPackageName()));
          image.setBackgroundResource("R.drawable." +dreaw);
                    }
            }
        });

              image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
}
```

i am new in android i want to change my image when i pressed my button image 
in this line `image.setBackgroundResource("R.drawable." +dreaw);` it shows error how i can fix it please help me.

Comment: Please edit your post and add errors.

Comment: K.You havent yet solved your problem.May i know the list of Drawables you want to use in your for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that :

```
Drawable dreaw = getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("d002_p00"+j, "dreaw",getPackageName()));
image.setBackgroundResource("R.drawable." +dreaw);
```

Try :

```
Drawable dreaw = getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("d002_p00"+j, "dreaw",getPackageName()));
image.setBackground(dreaw);
```

Answer (score 1):

R.drawable.xxx is not a string it is a auto genarated intiger id for each resources.

image.setBackgroundResource("R.drawable." +dreaw);is wrong.

you can do onething

```
int res=getResources().getIdentifier("d002_p00"+j, "drawable",getPackageName()));
```

image.setBackgroundResource(res);

Comment: it worked bt it showa my first and last image.
@Koushik

Comment: it worked bt it showa my first and last image.  @Koushik

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
image.setBackgroundDrawable(dreaw);
```

This method is deprecated from api level 16 but fro backword compatibility you should use above method.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
image.setBackgroundDrawable(drew);
```

Answer (score 0):

As your comment quotes "*it worked bt it showa my first and last image.*"

You can only see the first and last image.Because the `for` loop is in a hurry burry,that means you can't see the changing of image,because the `for` loop is executed within **ms(Milli or Micro Seconds)**.So you want to put this

```
Thread.sleep(<put_how_much_ms_you_want_to_make_the_for_loop_sleep);
```

to sleep the for loop time to time.If you put this

```
Thread.sleep(1000);//Make the thread or program blocked for 1 second.
```

For implementing in your `For` loop you can change your `For` loop like this.

```
 for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++)
 {
      int res=getResources().getIdentifier("d002_p00"+j, "drawable",getPackageName()));
      image.setBackgroundResource(res);
      Thread.sleep(1000);//Make the for loop wait for 1 second.
 }
```

By this you can see the transition of images.
May i know it helps you or not.